# Regardless of what I choose in the drop-down box, it only gives the same font whenever I press Enter

Tags: javascript, html

What is the problem? I keep getting green fonts regardless of whether I choose "Pass", "Fail" or "Borderline". I hope someone can help me fix it so that whenever I choose Pass I get the name and green font in the list, Fail will give me the name and a red font while Borderline will give me the name and the orange font, thanks!

````
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
  Enter Student Name <input type="text" id="name">&nbsp;
  Grade <select id="gradism">
    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
    <option value="Borderline">Borderline</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;<button type="button" id="enter" onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
</form>
<h1>Students</h1>

<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>
selected = document.getElementById("gradism").value
if (selected == "Pass") {
  function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("list").style.color = "#00FF00";
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(userName);
    li.appendChild(node);
    if (userName.trim().length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
      document.getElementById("form").reset()
    }
  }
}
else if (selected == "Fail") {
  function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("list").style.color = "#FF0000";
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(userName);
    li.appendChild(node);
    if (userName.trim().length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
      document.getElementById("form").reset()
    }
  }
}
else if (selected == "Borderline") {
  function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("list").style.color = "#FFA500";
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(userName);
    li.appendChild(node);
    if (userName.trim().length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
      document.getElementById("form").reset()
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is this: when the page loads your logic gets evaluated. Immediately your conditional runs and the page decides which of the functions it will use. It's never changing because it all evaluates once when the page loads

When you want to test for a conditional, do it inside a single function, rather than create multiple functions for each outcome. In this case it also means we won't test for the value of the pulldown UNTIL the function is run. Also, since you're changing the style of your elements, lets use classes. Much easier to work with and more scalable. We can simply pass the value of the pulldown directly to the new element as a class with `li.classList.add(color.toLowerCase())`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let color = document.getElementById("gradism").value
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.classList.add(color.toLowerCase())
  var node = document.createTextNode(userName);
  li.appendChild(node);
  if (userName.trim().length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("form").reset()
  }
}
```

```css
.pass {
  color: #00FF00;
}

.borderline {
  color: #FFA500;
}

.fail {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  Enter Student Name <input type="text" id="name">&nbsp; Grade
  <select id="gradism">
    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
    <option value="Borderline">Borderline</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;<button type="button" id="enter" onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
</form>
<h1>Students</h1>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: great! if this helped you solve your question, please consider marking it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers